# Получение метода из другого класса

Tags: java, android

Дело, в том, что этот код я использую в одном классе. Но мне нужно еще в трех классах этот метод. Повторять коды везде, не правильно. 
Если в классе без унаследования от `Activity`, будут проблемы с `getActivity()` или `getContext()`, я думаю. Поэтому хотелось бы узнать, как правильно получить доступ к этому методы из разных классов?

```
    public String loadJSONFromAsset() {
        String json = null;
        try {
            InputStream is = getActivity().getAssets().open("cities_json.json");
            int size = is.available();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
            is.read(buffer);
            is.close();
            json = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        return json;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Создаете класс, который занимается работой с JSON'ом, не забывайте про принцип единой ответственности. Потом экземпляр этого класса в классе, где хотите его использовать и используйте. Вот самый простой пример:

```
class JSONHelper {
    public String loadJSONFromAsset(Context context, String fileName) {
        try(InputStream is = context.getAssets().open(fileName)) {
            int size = is.available();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
            is.read(buffer);

            return new String(buffer, "UTF-8");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            //Опишите возвращение null в документации
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Потом в требуемом месте создаете экземпляр этого класса и используете:

```
class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private JSONHelper mJsonHelper = new JSONHelper();
    ...

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        mJsonHelper.loadJsonFromAssets(this, "cities_json.json");
    }

}
```

Этот класс можно использовать в разных местах, при чем работать можно с контекстом, что намного удобнее контекса `Activity`.

Comment: Если есть возможность избежать такой реализации, то лучше так не делать. utility-классы нарушают инкапсуляцию и делают код сильно связанным. Плюс код с utility-классами труднее тестировать.

Comment: @RafaelOsipov, если человек спрашивает о том, как вообще такое делать, не следует ему рассказывать о внедрении зависимостей. Понятно, что на практике так делать не всегда желательно.

Comment: @RafaelOsipov, только без utility-классов код превращается в кашу, в которой никто не знает, что делать. Тестированию он поддается в разы хуже, при чем даже юнит тестам.

Comment: призывать меня помнить о принципе единой ответственности и в то-же время поддерживать идею внедрения utility-классов со статическими методами - это интересно, да. Спасибо.

Comment: @RafaelOsipov, эм... Мой класс выполняет единственную функцию, что очень хорошо и отвечает всем канонам чистого кода. Utility-классы - неотъемлемый элемент любого хорошего проекта. Где Вы увидели статический метод? Я их не использую, потому что они скрывают зависимости. Мой код абсолютной соответствует всем принципам чистого кода, в то время как Ваш - нарушает их везде, где только можно.

Comment: Хорошо, Ростислав.